# Index of percentage of the population working from home or independently by county

Tags: data-request

I would like to know which counties have the higher percentage of people working from home, or self-employed with a decent income. I wonder where I could find a decent chart with rankings corresponding to these

Comment: https://data.oecd.org/emp/self-employment-rate.htm (Working at home will be harder to find globally)